# HTML: send image in mailto?body

Tags: html, email, mailto

I am used to setting the body and subject of an email with text with the mailto function, eg:

```
href="mailto:?body=Thanks!"
```

But is there a way to send an image in the body? Eg:

```
href="mailto:?body=<img src='http://www.example.com/image.jpg'>"
```

(obviously above doesn't work - it just adds the html as a string)

Any advice appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [horse's mouth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368):

> The "body" hname should contain the content for    the first
> text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is    primarily
> intended for generation of short text messages that are    actually
> the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"    messages
> for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

In other words, the content is in text/plain format, not MIME HTML.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not possible. `mailto` is limited to send texts and promotional msgs, so you cant attach an image with `mailto`.