# How does one put images into a Lotus Notes email generated from the command line?

Tags: powershell, email, cmd, lotus-notes

I'm able to [use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623043/trouble-processing-parameters-when-creating-a-new-email-in-ibm-notes-from-powers) to generate emails, but is there a way to include images in the emails from the command line?  Maybe using base64 encoding or something like that?

I've also seen a few copy/pastes where I ended up with `<324d21q.jpg>` and I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: These are not Notes-specific, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374026/150605), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680855/150605), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415988/150605) say you cannot use `mailto:` links to embed images or arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending mail from HTML page with image in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373737/sending-mail-from-html-page-with-image-in-the-body)

Comment: Once again, you need to show your actual script. You didn't in your previous question, and you didn't elaborate on it when you posted an answer to it. It's still not obvious what you're doing in your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: send image in mailto?body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680826/html-send-image-in-mailtobody)